# Why is this procedures giving me errors?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Just doing a project told us to do the database and i've to do also some procedures, i've done the next one:

```
create procedure insert_inci
(
@Name varchar(50),
@Description varchar(250),
@CodeAU int,
@CodeC int,
@CodeP int
)
begin
insert into incidencia(Name, Description,CodeAU,CodeC,CodeP) values (@Name, @Description,@CodeAU,@CodeC,@CodeP)
end;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE update_incidencia
AS
(
@CodeI int,
@Name varchar(50),
@Description varchar(250),
@CodeAU int,
@CodeC int,
@CodeP int
)
update incidencia set @Name=Name,@Description=Description, @CodeAU=CodeAU,@CodeC=CodeC, @CodeP=CodeP
where @CodeI=CodeI
END;
GO
```

But this is giving me syntax errors, and i don't even know how to solve them, that are two examples of the procedures i've to do, anyone see errors in there?

Comment: This looks a little like SQL Server code (with the `GO` operations). And, you may have forgotten MySQL's `DELIMITER` issue with stored procedure definitions. Take a look at some examples, e.g. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Comment: I can use variables inside delimiters?

I just tried that method (IN) and it worked as the examples that the page gives, but i don't really know how to use variables for it, i've just done one select procedure

Comment: The delimiter issue relates to the semicolons at the end of lines of code, not to the syntax of particular statements. *Please* look at some MySQL Stored Procedure examples with your favorite search engine.